# How to commit changes on a branch? And then how to avoid pulling that branch into production?

Tags: git

I am currently on the master branch. I have been making a lot of changes locally. What I would like to achieve is to move these changes to another branch, and push them to the repository. But when in production I run `git pull`, I don't want it to also pull the changes I've set aside on that branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To push your changes onto a separate branch, you simply need to create a new branch at your current commit. You can then reset your local `master` to `origin/master` to remove those commits from your master branch.

```
git branch my-branch
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Now when you push the branches, the commits will be on the desired branches.

As for the second question, you can specify which branch you want to pull so that only that branch gets pulled.

```
git pull origin master
```

Comment: Thank you @Ali Samji. Before running `git reset --hard origin/master` do I need to go back to the main branch?

Comment: When I followed the steps, I did not have to checkout master again. The `git branch` command branched the code but kept me on the `master` branch.  But that was a good thing to keep in mind. You want to make  sure to execute the `git reset --hard` only when you have the master branch checked out.

Comment: Thank you @benhorgen . When I then go to push to repository, do I also push the branch? And at a later time will I be able to merge the secondary branch with the main branch?

Comment: The answer to both is yes. While you don't have to push the branch, it is a good idea to do so to keep a back up of your work on the remote server. As for merging the secondary branch back to master, you can absolutely do that. You can do a rebase/merge, merge commit, or a fast-forward merge depending on your needs.

Comment: @AliSamji Sorry, I want to make sure I'm not making a mistake. Does `git pull origin master` cause only the master and not the branches to be pulled in production?

Comment: Yes. Only the master branch will be pulled. The other branches will not be available locally unless you pull them.